# CodeBlocks IDE on MacBook - Debugging

Tags: c, macos, debugging, codeblocks

for school we need to develop in C. So our teacher recommended us to use CodeBlocks as the IDE for development. I have a MacBook for development, because I'am using Xamarin for writing apps.

Now I have installed CodeBlocks but unfortunately I cant debug my terminal app.

After I start the debugging-session the terminal shows up, but somehow it does not load my app. Running the app without debugger works fine.

PS: I have installed GDB by HomeBrew.

This is the console output:

> Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
>
> Selecting target:
>
> Debug
>
> Adding source dir:
>   /Users/me/Documents/CodeBlocksProjects/test1/
>
> Adding source dir:
>   /Users/me/Documents/CodeBlocksProjects/test1/
>
> Adding file:
>   /Users/me/Documents/CodeBlocksProjects/test1/bin/Debug/test1
>
> Changing directory to:
>   /Users/me/Documents/CodeBlocksProjects/test1/.
>
> Set variable: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.: Starting debugger:
>   /usr/local/bin/gdb -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args
>   /Users/me/Documents/CodeBlocksProjects/test1/bin/Debug/test1
>
> done
>
> Registered new type: wxString
>
> Registered new type: STL String
>
> Registered new type: STL Vector
>
> Setting breakpoints
>
> Can't launch console (osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"' -e 'activate'
>   -e 'do script ""' -e 'end tell' sleep 80000467)
>
> Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.10
>
> No stack.

Comment: "Registered new type: STL Vector" does not look like C. Take the [tour], learn [ask] and post a [mcve] along with the other required information.

Comment: If your code is a standalone .c file CodeBlocks won't allow it to be debugged ! But if you create a new project of c/c++ it would allow you to! Experience on windows